# What are the date_default_timezones of these?

Tags: php

Alaska,
Atlantic,
Central,
Eastern,
GMT +10,
Hawaii,
Mountain,
Pacific,
Pacific +4,
Pacific +7,
Samoa,

I am a bit confused by http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Hoping to get some appreciated help!

Comment: if you checked properly you will get. click on the right side on each country and search for the above you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out

```
Alaska America/Anchorage
Atlantic America/Puerto_Rico
Central America/Chicago
Eastern America/New_York
GMT +10 Pacific/Guam
Hawaii America/Adak
Mountain America/Denver
Pacific America/Dawson_Creek
Pacific +4 Pacific/Fiji
Pacific +7 Pacific/Palau
Samoa Pacific/Samoa
```